# Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, components

There are a bunch of similar questions on so, but I can't see one that matches my conundrum.

I have a react component (a radial knob control - kinda like a slider).
I want to achieve two outcomes:

1. Twiddle the knob and pass the knob value up to the parent for further actions.
2. Receive a target knob value from the parent and update the knob accordingly.
3. All without going into an endless loop!

I have pulled my hair out - but have a working solution that seems to violate react principles.

I have **knob.js** as a react component that wraps around the third party knob component and I have **app.js** as the parent.

In knob.js, we have:

```
export default class MyKnob extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context)

        this.state = {
            size: props.size || 100,
            radius: (props.value/2).toString(),
            fontSize: (props.size * .2)
        }
        if (props.value){
            console.log("setting value prop", props.value)
            this.state.value = props.value
        } else {
            this.state.value = 25           // any old default value
        }

      }
```

To handle updates from the parent (app.js) I have this in knob.js:

```
      // this is required to allow changes at the parent to update the knob
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
           this.setState({value: this.props.value})
        }
        console.log("updating knob from parent", value)
      }
```

and then to pass changes in knob value back to the parent, I have:

```
    handleOnChange = (e)=>{
        //this.setState({value: e})    <--used to be required until line below inserted. 
        this.props.handleChangePan(e)
      }
```

This also works but triggers a warning:

> Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Knob`)

```
render(){
        return (
            <Styles font-size={this.state.fontSize}>
            <Knob size={this.state.size}  
                angleOffset={220} 
                angleRange={280}
                steps={10}
                min={0}
                max={100}
                value={this.state.value}
                ref={this.ref}
                onChange={value => this.handleOnChange(value)}
            >
...
```

Now over to app.js:

```
function App() {
  const [panLevel, setPanLevel] = useState(50);

// called by the child knob component. works -- but creates the warning
    function handleChangePan(e){
      setPanLevel(e)
    }

    // helper function for testing
    function changePan(e){
      if (panLevel + 10>100){
        setPanLevel(0)
      } else {
        setPanLevel(panLevel+10)
      }
    }

return (
    <div className="App">
        ....
        <div className='mixer'>
          <div key={1} className='vStrip'>
            <Knob size={150} value={panLevel} handleChangePan = {(e) => handleChangePan(e)}/>
          </div>
        <button onClick={(e) => changePan(e)}>CLICK ME TO INCREMENT BY 10</button>
      ...
    </div>
```

So - it works -- but I am violating react principles -- I haven't found another way to keep the external "knob value" and the internal "knob value" in sync.

Just to mess with my head further, if I remove the bubbling to parent in 'handleOnChange' - which presumably then triggers a change in prop-->state cascading back down - I not only have a lack of sync with the parent -- but I also need to reinstate the setState below, in order to get the knob to work via twiddling (mouse etc.._)! This creates another warning:

> Update during an existing state transition...

So stuck. Advice requested and gratefully received. Apols for the long post.

```
    handleOnChange = (e)=>{
        //this.setState({value: e})
        **this.props.handleChangePan(e)**
      }
```

It has been suggested on another post, that one should wrap the setState into a useEffect - but I can't figure out how to do that - let alone whether it's the right approach.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message will be displayed if parent (App) states are set while rendering children (Knob).

In your case, while App is rendering, Knob's`onChange()` is triggered when loaded, which then calls `this.handleOnChange()` and then `this.props.handleChangePan()` having App's`setPanLevel()`.

To fix using `useEffect()`:

1. In `knob.js`, you can store `panLevel` as state first just like in App, instead of direct calling `this.props.handleChangePan()` to call App's`setPanLevel()`.
2. Then, use `useEffect(_=>props.handleChangePan(panLevel),[panLevel])` to call App's`setPanLevel()` via `useEffect()`.

Your knob.js will look like this:

```js
function Knob(props){
  let [panLevel, setPanLevel] = useState(50);
  useEffect(_=>{
    props.handleChangePan(panLevel);
  }, [panLevel]);
  return *** Knob that does not call props.handleChangePan(), but call setPanLevel() instead ***;
}
```

`setState()` called inside `useEffect()` will be effective after the render is done.

In short, you cannot call parent's`setState()` outside `useEffect()` while in first rendering, or the error message will come up.