# Cannot update a component (`Connect(withRouter(DesktopHeader))`) while rendering a different component (`Router.Consumer`)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have been looking into this problem at many places, but still not understanding the actual cause behind it. Here are some references that I looked into:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly1AB.png)https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178

[2][Warning: Cannot update a component while rendering a different component. ReactRedux.Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67018543/warning-cannot-update-a-component-while-rendering-a-different-component-reactr)

[3][Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236000/cannot-update-a-component-app-while-rendering-a-different-component)

Reproducible Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-hooks-idqo2?file=/src/App.js
(To see the warning you need to go to about page or any page and refresh the browser)

And many such other issue. Though I understand all of these cause to the same problem, but I am not getting what actually is the issue?

Here is my code and I am using react-redux:

```
import Aux from "./hoc/Auxilary";
import HeaderPage from "./Components/HeaderPage";
import HomePage from "./Components/Pages/Home/Home";
import AboutPage from "./Components/Pages/About/AboutPage";
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    activeLink: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({...this.state,activeLink:this.props.global.activeNavBar});
  }

  render()
  {
  return (
    <Aux>
        {/*<img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />*/}
        <BrowserRouter>
        <HeaderPage Active = {this.state.activeLink}/>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <HomePage />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/about" render={() => {
          this.props.onIndirectLink("About");
          return <AboutPage / >
        }}/>
        <Route exact path="/credits" render={() => {
          this.props.onIndirectLink("Credits");
          return <div>Credits</div>
        }}/>
        <Route exact path="/contact" render={() => {
          this.props.onIndirectLink("Contact");
          return <div>Credits</div>
        }}/>
      </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Aux>

  );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {

  return {

    global:state.appGlobal
    
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {

  return {

    onIndirectLink: (key) => dispatch({type: "INDIRECTLINK",payload: {key: key}})

  };

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Here's my Active Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "../../assets/logo.png";
import classes from "./Headers.module.css";
import Button from "../ui/Button";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

//https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp
class DesktopHeader extends Component {

    state = {
        activeStyle: {color: "#00B0F0",borderBottom: "1px solid red"},
        inactiveStyle: {color: "#fff",borderBottom: "none"},
        itemList: {About:"About",Contact:"Contact",Credits:"Credits"},
        routelist:{About:"about",Contact:"contact",Credits:"credits"}
    }

    navBarClickHandler = (key) => {
        this.props.onClickUpdate(key);
        this.setState({});
        this.props.history.push(`/${this.state.routelist[key]}`);

    }

    render()
    {
        const renderLinks = Object.keys(this.state.itemList).map(element => {

            if(this.props.global.activeNavBar === element)
            return <div className = {classes.NavigationContent} 
            key = {element}
            style = {this.state.activeStyle}
            onClick = {() => this.navBarClickHandler(element)}
            >{this.state.itemList[element]}</div>
            else
            return <div className = {classes.NavigationContent}
            key = {element}
            onClick = {() => this.navBarClickHandler(element)}
            >{this.state.itemList[element]}</div>

        });
        return (
            <div className = {classes.CompleteHeader}>
            
                    <div className = {classes.LogoAndLogin}>

                            <div className = {classes.LogoClass}>
                            <img src={logo} onClick = {() => {
                                this.props.onClickUpdate(null);
                                this.props.history.push("/");
                            }} 
                            className = {classes.LogoImage} alt = {"Logo"}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className = {classes.LoginButtonContainer}>
                            <Button className = {[classes.LoginButton,classes.Dark].join(" ")}>Login</Button>
                            </div>
                    </div>


                    <div className = {classes.NavigationLinks}>

                                {renderLinks}


                    </div>

            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {

    return {
  
      global:state.appGlobal
      
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  
    return {
  
      onClickUpdate: (key) => dispatch({type: "INDIRECTLINK",payload: {key: key}})
  
    };
  
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(DesktopHeader));
```

I am unable to understand where exactly is it going wrong?

My `HeaderPage` has three nav links as shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HeaderDesktop from "./Headers/HeaderDesktop";
import HeaderMobile from "./Headers/HeaderMobile";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
class HeaderPage extends Component {

    state = {

        deviceType: "Desktop",

    };

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this));
        this.resize();
    }
    
    resize() {
        const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        let deviceType = "Desktop";
        if(windowWidth <= 400)
        {
            deviceType = "Mobile";
        }
        else if(windowWidth > 400 && windowWidth <= 540)
        {
            deviceType = "Tablet";
        }
        this.setState({...this.state,deviceType: deviceType});
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this));
    }

    render()
    {
        
        if(this.state.deviceType !== "Mobile")
        return <HeaderDesktop Active = {this.props.Active}/>
        else
        return <HeaderMobile Active = {this.props.Active}/>
        
    }

};

export default withRouter(HeaderPage);
```

Here's an example of the issue:
[image]

Comment: I don't see how the second snippet relates to the first but if I had to guess, it's the `this.setState({});` in the `navBarClickHandler` right before you (*possibly*) navigate to another route. This state update is likely unnecessary. Can you explain the issue and steps to reproduce in a bit more detail? Your code also stands to benefit from using [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) components to know which path is active.

Comment: @DrewReese, thanks Sorry I just forgot to add the linking. Let me update my question, removed the `setState` method as you mentioned but no effect, the warning still remains. One thing I would like to add is though everything behaves exactly as expected but still the warning comes up

Comment: @DrewReese Here is the reproducible sandbox for the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-hooks-idqo2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What is this codesandbox supposed to do? All I see is an image of a "G" with an ear of corn, and nothing happens when it is clicked.

Comment: When you load about page and refresh it is when it shows that warning... Just check the image that I have attached into the question. It all works fine until I directly jump to a specific link like `/about`

Comment: It is the dispatching of `INDIRECTLINK` action in your router. Seems you are trying to set what "link" is active (again, see my suggestion in original comment). What is `onIndirectLink` for? Why not just use `Link` or `NavLink` components from `react-router-dom`? Seems silly to store this data in your redux store.

Comment: I see... okay makes sense, I am going to shift it to navLink, it's that I wasn't much familiar and confident with navLink and that's why used this method... But anyways, just out of curiosity, if in case there won't be any navLink how possibly could we modify the links? Additionally onIndirect link is to set a navlink active when someone directly redirect to `/about` or `/contact` page rather than going to `/` and then clicking about.

Comment: NavLink - "A special version of the `<Link>` that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it ***matches*** the current URL." If there is a current match it will be active. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink